# Destroy CFrameWnd object without initialization

Tags: c++, mfc

I create new frame like this:

```
CFrameWnd* frame = CreateNewFrame(document, NULL);
```

Sometimes (it depends on specified conditions) I don't call `CFrameWnd::InitialUpdateFrame()` because I not want draw the window, but I must destroy this frame.

When I destroy the frame as follow (without call `CFrameWnd::InitialUpdateFrame()`)

```
frame->DestroyWindow();
```

previous view is freezing. How to fix it?

Comment: Note that you can call `InitialUpdateFrame()` with the second argument set to `FALSE` in order to initialize the frame without showing it.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, I have tried to use `InitialUpdateFrame()` with `bMakeVisible` argument set to `FALSE`, but result is the same as before - prevoius view is freezing. This construction works correctly only if the `bMakeVisible` argument in `InitialUpdateFrame()` is set to `TRUE`.

Comment: Whre does it freeze. Runit in the debuggr. Hit Break All and locate the code in the call stack!